# How to implement Disqus counter in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, disqus

I'm trying to implement a disqus counter following [this official tutorial](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624#non-link-elements) in my angular application. But I can't see any number, all that's displayed is "First article" which is the text in the span element that should be replaced with the counts if I'm getting it right.

1) I've added the count.js in my index.html right before the body closing tag (and used my site's name, not an example like here):

```
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//mysite.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
```

2) As I'm using [Angular UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) I guess I shouldn't use counts for links but rather an [identifier](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624#non-link-elements):

```
<span class="disqus-comment-count" data-disqus-identifier="test">First article</span>
```

3) The identifier is also specified in the config:

```
 this.page.identifier = 'test';
```

As my language settings specified in the config get applied I believe the config is initiated.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Having similar problems with AngularJS and Disqus

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the problem yet.

Comment: yeah im still going to try to get my disqus directive to work if i can't im going to bower install one someone else made and reverse engineer theirs. Ill keep you posted.

Comment: so i took out my own custom code and then used a third party angular-disqus library and it worked. so i cant figure out what the differences were. maybe try a library and see if that works then go back and try your code and use the library as a template.